# Does $AB$ possess inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is $m \times n$ of rank $m$. $B$ is $n \times m$ of rank $m$. Does $AB$ possesses inverse?

I know that $A$ has full row rank. So it has right inverse. So, $AD=I$ for some $B$. Similarly, $CB=I$ for some $C$. Is the inverse is combination of $C$ and $D$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \end{bmatrix}$, $B$= $\begin{bmatrix}
&1\\
&0
\end{bmatrix}$. Then $AB=0$